# In venture IT company with about 5 developers and 1 tester, which unit test level should be token?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, mockito, junit4

Our company has 5 developers and 1 tester, and now we build a platform with Jersey, Spring-boot and spring-data-jpa and so on. And when we discuss about how to setup test framework with Mockito, Junit4, many voices comes. There are those ways:

1. Write unit test for testing Resource, Service and Repository.
2. Just write integration test case which access to DB, which will enable the JTA transaction and ensure the correctness of code.
3. Combine them but how to do it is a big problem.

Who can help me make this decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Balance effort and risk reduction**

You want to write your tests such that you get the most reduction in failure risk for the given effort. Very roughly speaking:

Failure risk is high

- where the logic in your code is complicated
- where the design of your code is complicated (e.g. many callers)
- where complex technology is used which you understand only roughly
- where changes are or will be performed frequently.

Effort is low

- where a unit test can be written straightforwardly (e.g. without mocking)
- where your code does not maintain state
- where an integration test exercises a lot of your functionality.

You should invest in testing where these two areas overlap.
And design your code such that this overlap forms a large area.
I am simplifying a lot here, but the suggestions 1) and 2) of your
question simplify even more.
Beware of any one-size-fits all answer.

The question **"Should I write this test?"** is effectively the combination of
"What could go wrong here?", "How much risk reduction does the test give me?",
and "Does that pay off the effort for implementing the test?".
Of course you never know any of the answers precisely, 
but even a rough estimate is often a sensible guide for deciding
strongly for a possible test A or against a possible test B, 
especially in direct comparison of A and B.

Comment: Thanks for your conclusion on failure risk and effort. In most situation, selection is hard. And the quality of developer is important. I have my answer: integration test is need and unit test for situation where failure risk is high is for selection.